# Error adding objects to a PFRelation, how is this done?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, pfrelation

I am trying to get my head around PFRelation in parse. I have a class called "girlBio" that stores information about girls and a class called "stuff" that stores information about items. code below:

```
PFObject *item = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"stuff"];
item[@"Name"] = @"PS3";
PFObject *girl = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"girlBio"];
girl[@"Name"] = @"Jessica";
PFObject *girl2 = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"girlBio"];
girl2[@"Name"] = @"Cindy";

PFRelation *relation = [item relationForKey:@"owners"];
[relation addObject:girl];
[relation addObject:girl2];
[item saveInBackground];
```

--------------------------------- update also tried this -------------------------

```
PFObject *item = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"stuff"];
item[@"Name"] = @"PS3";
PFObject *girl = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"girlBio"];
girl[@"Name"] = @"Jessica";
[item saveInBackground];
[girl saveInBackground];
PFRelation *relation = [item relationForKey:@"owners"];
[relation addObject:girl];
[item saveInBackground];
```

So I want this item to be owned by several girls however when I run the program I get this error:

*Error: can't add a non-pointer to a relation (Code: 111, Version: 1.6.0)*

Can someone help please?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to save your objects `girl1` and `girl2` before saving the relationship. Otherwise, even thought your local copy knows about them, the server does not.

UPDATE

You also need to make sure the saves for `girl1` and `girl2` and `item` complete before you save the relation. However, you probably don't want to run these saves on the primary thread, so I'd recommend something like this (which I just ran without issue):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    PFObject *item = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"stuff"];
    item[@"Name"] = @"PS3";
    PFObject *girl = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"girlBio"];
    girl[@"Name"] = @"Jessica";
    [item save];
    [girl save];
    PFRelation *relation = [item relationForKey:@"owners"];
    [relation addObject:girl];
    [item saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        //Do something after the last save...
    }];
});
```

Comment: just tried this, see edited code above. still exactly the same error. grrrr. It's driving me mad.

Comment: I'm going to try this myself exactly as you wrote it and get it working. Might need to save in nested blocks to ensure a save prior to setting and saving the PFRelation. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Updated answer above - give that a try.

Comment: Thank you so much. Totally understand now. The girl object has to finish saving before we query it again, therefore we create the relation in a completion block not outside in the main thread. Added my code above. Pretty similar to yours. Thanks again for the help. Really appreciate it.